# DC to AC converter

Tags: ac, dc, converter, waveform

I know there are lots of circuits that do this, but I need to design a circuit that has a DC input and a square wave output by using any of these components:
capacitors, inductors, OpAmps, resistors, diodes, and a dc power supply 
To be more specific, the square wave should have a duty cycle of 20%
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried replicating a 555 yet?

Comment: Is this for an assignment?

Comment: Here's an idea: make an attempt at designing the circuit, come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution to understand, given those components, would be an RC oscillator, followed by a comparator.

1. Design your RC oscillator to give the frequency you want. See, for example, http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/rc_oscillator.html
2. Feed the oscillator output into the input of a comparator, with the threshold voltage proportional to the duty. See, for example, http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html

Note this solution doesn't require the diode - not sure if there's a more elegant solution that involves diodes.